# freemarker string split and substring

Tags: string, yaml, freemarker

I have a string in the following format

```
aa_bbbbb_ccccc
```

length of aa is fixed and b's and c's are of variable length. I need to capture the `bbbbb` from this string using freemarker.

Answer (score 0):

If `s` stores that string, the expression `s?split('_')[1]` evaluates to `bbbbb`.